# searching database with regular expression condition using php

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have database as following:

```
database name=words , table name=collection, column name=word
word
----
vivek
nidhi
neha
sidhu
hin
```

I need to search an array of strings with regular expression condition:

```
<?php
$array=array('vivek','nidhi','neha','akshay','nitin','nid','nih','hin');
@ $db=new mysqli('localhost','root','','words');
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Error:Could not connect to the database';
}
else
echo 'connected';
$db->select_db('words');
$count = 0;
foreach($array as $s)
{    
    if(preg_match('/^[nidhi]+$/', $s))
    {
    $query="select * from collection where word LIKE '%".$s."%'";
    $result=$db->query($query);
    if($result)
    $count += $result->num_rows;
    }   

}
echo $count;
$db->close();
?>
```

i am using `'/^[nidhi]+$/'` regular expression so I should get only `2 ans i.e. nidhi,hin` but my problem is I am geting `3 ans i.e nidhi,nid,hin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are currently doing is matching the words, which are formed from any of the characters in `nidhi`.

If you need to match only `nidhi` and `hin` then you should pipe (`|`) the words in the exression:

```
if(preg_match('/^nidhi|hin$/', $s))
```

Comment: no i need to match all the words that are formed by the alphabets n,i,d,h,i that combines and become '/^[nidhi]+$/' regular expression.

Comment: `nid` whats the problem with it? it also formed from `[nidhi]`.

Comment: but checkout the database entries. 'nid' is not in the database. this regular expression is being used to filter strings that are formed with 'n','i','d','h'

Comment: Your sql query has `'%".$s."%'`. So when you use nid here it becomes `%nid%`. That why your `nid` and `nidhi` both matches with `nidhi` in your database.

Comment: Try `REGEXP '^".$s."$'` instead of `LIKE '%".$s."%'`